# Why is the differential of a little-o also a little-o?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-fields

Let's consider a vector field ($C^{\infty}$)
$$X : \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{V}$$
where $\mathcal{A}$ is an affine space with underlying vector space $\mathcal{V}$.

Let's assume that, for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, we have a diffeomorphism
$$\phi_t : \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$$
s.t. $\phi_t(A) = \gamma_A(t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $A \in \mathcal{A}$, where
$$\gamma_A : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$$
is the solution of the Cauchy problem
\begin{cases}
(d\gamma_A/dt)(t) = X(\gamma_A(t)) \\
\gamma_A(0) = A
\end{cases}

With this assumptions, we have that, for fixed $A \in \mathcal{A}$, the difference
$$\phi_t(A) - A - tX(A) = \gamma_A(t) - A - tX(A)$$
is a little-o of $t$, for $t \rightarrow 0$.

Why can we conclude that also its differential (recall that $\phi_t$ is a diffeomorhpism)
$$\nabla_A\phi_t - \text{id}_{\mathcal{V}} - t\nabla_AX$$
is a little-o of $t$, for $t \rightarrow 0$?